# How to find out my Adyen token?

Tags: android, payment, adyen

I'm trying out Adyen for mobile payments and got stuck on step 1...

I made a demo activity with a button that will launch the `PaymentActivity`.
Here's some code to elaborate:

```
    btnCheckout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_checkout);
    btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckoutRequest checkoutRequest = new CheckoutRequest();
            try {
                checkoutRequest.setBrandColor(R.color.adyen_green);
                checkoutRequest.setBrandLogo(R.drawable.pay_button);
                checkoutRequest.setCheckoutAmount(1.01f);
                checkoutRequest.setCurrency(Currency.EUR);
                //checkoutRequest.setToken(your_token);
                checkoutRequest.setToken("thisISmyToken");
                checkoutRequest.setTestBackend(true);//default is set to false. Set it to true if you want to use Adyen's test back-end.

                Intent intent = new PaymentActivity.PaymentActivityBuilder(checkoutRequest).build(MainActivity.this, getBaseContext());
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (CheckoutRequestException e) {
                Log.e("SHARK", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    });
```

how and where exactly do I find out this `your_token` ? I've read about finding it under CA -> Settings/Users but.... I don't see a token I should use anywhere. and I lost the link as well :/

Please, kindly help as I can't even try out the sample code without the token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After contacting support and messing around, I realized I was an idiot.

The easiest way to do it is, quoting from the support email:

The token can be found via:

> Settings >> Users >> System Users >> Click on the 'ws' user. You will
>   find the link to the library:
>
> https://test.adyen.com/hpp/cse/js/1234567890123456.shtml
>
> So your token is: 1234567890123456

It's the link that has a "Copy" button next to it.

Comment: You are not an idiot! It is not so obvious when you are using the interface for the first time!

Comment: Thanks man, I agree but I just had a very different feeling after wasting too much time on this and having to contact support.